# Is this site cloaking to hide my backlink from spiders?

Tags: web-crawlers, backlinks, google-cache, cloaking

I wrote a guest post at the following URL:

`https://wparena.com/integrate-google-tag-manager-wordpress/`

At the end, you can see my author box with a URL pointing back to my site. This link is a regular "follow" link and the page doesn't have "noindex" on it.

However, I'm not getting credit for it. It's not showing up in Google search console, and it hasn't been indexed by ahrefs However, a week later the cached version doesn't show the author box.

```
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:cRTx81xI6zQJ:https://wparena.com/integrate-google-tag-manager-wordpress/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&lr=lang_en%7Clang_fr
```

In addition, the Moz link checker shows 0 external followed links from the page:

[image: No External Followed Links on Moz]

Can anyone help me figure out what's going on?

**TL;DR** Is the site hiding my backlink from spiders, and yet showing it to users on the browser? Is this legal?

Comment: Maybe Moz/ahrefs have not updated their index?  Also, have you checked your link, to see if there are any `rel=nofollow` or `rel=noindex` tags assigned to it?

Comment: @Craig It's already indexed by Moz. The problem is that it's showing different versions to viewers on browsers and other version to the spiders. Visit the link in your browser, and at the bottom you will see a backlink to my site. Retrieve it as a spider, and there's no link!

Comment: As you can see in the Google cached version, then entire <section> element is missing, and I'm not getting credit for the backlink anywhere. It shows only when viewed in the browser. Is it some Javascript? More to the point, is this entirely legal? (From a Google standpoint)?

Comment: IIRC Google has stated that they aren't big fans of links like this and they may be discounting or ignoring it

Comment: @JohnConde I think Google said that they're not fans of spammy guest posts and mass duplicate content on multiple sites. I very much doubt if anyone can call the article in my link "spammy". I put a lot of work into it! Not  to mention that my other guest posts show the backlink clearly, and I get full credit in the search console as well as on Moz and Ahrefs: https://tribulant.com/blog/wordpress/how-to-convert-a-post-to-a-page-in-wordpress/

Comment: Backlink sites are junk. They are so behind, they are relatively useless. As far as Google is concerned, they do not show all backlinks intentionally.

Comment: @closetnoc That's not my question though. My question is specifically about the backlink (or any link) not showing up in Google's cache. It's not about whether backlink sites are worth it, or whether Google thinks they're junk!

Comment: If you are talking about the pages cache, that is a whole other issue. If you are talking about Search Console, then what I commented is exactly right. Looking for backlinks on websites will consistently disappoint you.

Comment: Yeah, I'm first talking about the Google pages cache. That's why I asked if it's being hidden from spiders. Because if it's not showing there, then it can't show in the search console regardless of what Google thinks of them. So I'd like to start from there. Why is it not showing up in the Google cached versions?

Comment: Showing something different to users than to bots is called "cloaking".  I've edited your post to use that terminology.   You ask if it is "legal."  I doubt that there are any laws against it, but it is against the Google Webmaster guidelines: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for the response! Based on the link and cache I've shown, does it seem as of the website in question is indeed "cloaking" my backlink?

Comment: @BhagwadJalPark ... I could very well be wrong here but thought I would throw out a suggestion, should anyone else have a better idea:  I have noticed you have 2 link backs, on the site.  One within the Author Text Box's content and one within an Icon.  The latter has a `rel=nofollow`.  Could it be that if a URL has a `rel=nofollow`, then search engines treat all other duplicate links, on the same page, as a `rel=nofollow`, regardless of whether the attribute has been been assigned to them or not.

Comment: @BhagwadJalPark ... As for the Moz, are you using their new or old Tool?  They have stated that they are no longer updated their old Tool's Index database,  In fact, I *think* they are discontinuing their old Link Checker, as of the end of June 2018.

Comment: @Craig I appreciate the response! I'm using the new Moz tool (Link Checker I think it's called). Regarding the nofollow, it's an interesting point. But won't Google cache the nofollow links regardless? It might not pass link juice, but it should store the HTML of the page as is right? If it's not showing in the cached version, what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait, or better use Ahrefs. **Everything is ok with the backlink** - look at screenshot from Ahrefs.

Regarding Google cache - it is pretty inertly. Beside of this it should not be used to know, how Google sees your page. Read [this](https://maxxeight.com/blog/google-cache-seo/). One possible reason why you don't see the your author box with the link is, that this box is rendered by Javascript pretty late and the cache doesn't get it at all.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! So that's the reason huh? It's being rendered by Javascript and so it's not in the cache...And Ahrefs can't be smarter than Google, so hopefully Google's seen it too!

Comment: check in your web analytics, whether there were visits with referrer from wparena - if so, Google 146% knows about it ;)